# 1080p consider as 720p in jwplayer label

Tags: jwplayer, jwplayer6, jwplayer7

I set the different resolution in jwplayer it is working fine for me, only issue with the  HLS labels, I have 5 resolution 
(1)1080p
(2)720p
(3)480p
(4)360p
(5)240p

but 1080p set as 720p in jwplayer

[image]